# Rails file upload how to know if the image is sent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upload

I use the file_column plugin to upload an image in a form. The image field name is "image". I need to know if a file is sent when I upload the form (the image is optional). In fact, I want to update another field (image_updated_at) when the image is updated (in a after_validation callback).

So, I just want to know if an image is sent to update this field. The content of the params when there is an image is :

```
"image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x10750dae0 @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/p1/74mh4dd95zj0lpc42zm0h0kw0000gn/T/RackMultipart20120222-7745-s7rsy4-0>, @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"wine[image]\"; filename=\"montenero2006.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @content_type="image/jpeg", @original_filename="montenero2006.jpg">,
```

I just want to test if the image is sent. What to test instead of self.image ?

```
after_validation :set_image_date

def set_image_date
  self.image_updated_at = Time.now() if self.image
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for change on db attribute 
    after_validation :set_image_date

```
def set_image_date
  self.image_updated_at = Time.now() if changes[:image_file_name]
end
```

If you are not to sure about above solution then below is reliable solution

```
class Wine < ActiveRecord::Base

   def initialize(*args)
    args.merge!(:image_updated_at => Time.now) if args[:image].present?
    super
  end
end
```

Comment: Hum, don't work. Field image_updated_at never changed when I send a new image.

Comment: can you list the columns of table associate with model

Comment: I have a lot of columns, but there is just one for sending image named "image".

Comment: In fact, if image is sent/present, the params[:wine][:image] is present else it's not present.

Comment: I found a solution in the controller itself: `@wine.update_attributes(:image_updated_at => Time.now) if params[:wine][:image]`